# Flutter - FloatingActionButton is shown after going to next screen

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I tried a bottom navigation bar with Floating Action button as in the following link

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/2018-09-13-bottom-bar-navigation-with-fab/

It works well but when I move to next screen the floating button gets displayed and its funtion's are still working

I found a same type of issue(question) but no answer

[Flutter - FloatingActionButton isn't shown after going back a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361896/flutter-floatingactionbutton-isnt-shown-after-going-back-a-screen)

how to block the floating button visibility in upcoming screens

Answer (score 0):

please put your code. I am not aware of this problem but if you don't want it to be visible in a specific screen you can do so for example

```
_currentIndex==2? FloatingActionButton():Container()
```